# Canonical method to get the context of the parent template from within an event?

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-blaze

Given:

```
<template name="child">
  <button class=".child.button">Click Me</button>
</template>

<template name="parent">
  {{#each children}}
    {{> child }}
  {{/each}}  
</template>
```

I'd like to be able to have an event linked to the button in the child template that has access to the parent object.

**Possible solutions:**

I could store the parent in the dom and do something like:

```
Template.child.events({
  'click .child.button': function (event, template) {
    console.log('In this context \'this\' is the CHILD');
    // I want the parent object
    // I could pull a ref from the Dom? Seems messy.
    var parentId = $(event.currentTarget).closest('.parentClass').data('id');
    // Do something for this child using parent here
    return false;
  }
});
```

Or, I could hold the parent in a session var and pull it from there:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('parent', {
    path: '/parents/:_id',
    data: function () {
      // Get the current parent and put it into the session
      var thisparent = Parents.findOne(this.params._id);
      Session.set('currentParent', thisparent);
      return {
        parent: thisparent
      };
    }
  });
});
```

and then:

```
Template.child.events({
  'click .child.button': function (event, template) {
    console('the parent is: ', Session.get('currentProject'));
    return false;
  }
});
```

but ideally I'd prefer a cleaner solution and it feels like this should be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far you can not access the parent data from within a event using a API.

From within a helper you could use:

```
UI._parentData()
```

But from within a event this returns null.

Best solution is to use some [templating wizardry](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#with):

```
{{#each children}}
    {{#with context=this parent=..}}
        {{> child this}}
    {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

allowing:

```
Template.child.events({
  'click .child.button': function (event, template) {
    console('the parent context is: ', this.parent);
    console('the current context is: ', this.context);
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: That makes the code a lot more readable, thanks. I completed your answer with an example from the event.

Comment: @OliverLloyd No problem. Not only more readable but your Session scope solution would have problems with multiple tabs opened. And the dom data solution would be very susceptible to breaking due to small dom changes

Comment: Yeah, hence the question!

Comment: @OliverLloyd I would not put the context of child in this.child. Because the code in the event now suggests that you are actually getting something from the child of the child as this == child so this.child == child.child

Comment: Ah, so `this` maintains it's original context of child. That is: `this == child`? So you don't actually need to pass in this.context to maintain access to the original object?

Comment: @OliverLloyd In spark yes. But in blaze you either get the context or the arguments given. So parent=.. Doesnt add parent to the context it changes the context to { parent:object}. That's why we manually preserve the original context with context=this.